# Receive timeout while using redis as cache in play framework

Tags: playframework, redis, akka

I am using redis as cache to store data in Play framework application.
Redis module is enabled using following config in application.conf

play.modules.disabled += "play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"

Also library used while for redis integration is in build.sbt:-

libraryDependencies += "com.github.karelcemus" %% "play-redis" % "1.4.0"

I got error on set and get data in redis cache.

The exact error I am getting in application.log is:-

> [error] s.i.ListenerActor - Receive timeout [error] p.a.cache.redis -
>   Command GET classTag::_cursor_UPDATE_VAL for key 'GET' failed.
>   scredis.exceptions.RedisIOException: Receive timeout to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:6379  at
>   scredis.io.ListenerActor$$anonfun$reconnecting$1.applyOrElse(ListenerActor.scala:414)
>     at
>   scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170)
>     at
>   scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
>     at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:497)    at
>   scredis.io.ListenerActor.aroundReceive(ListenerActor.scala:27)    at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)  at
>   akka.actor.dungeon.DeathWatch$class.receivedTerminated(DeathWatch.scala:46)
>     at akka.actor.ActorCell.receivedTerminated(ActorCell.scala:374)     at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.autoReceiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:511)  at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:494)

I checked /var/log/redis/redis-server.log but file is empty.

After getting this error frequently, I restarted the server and was able set/get data in redis cache. redis runs fine for 7-8 days, I am able to set/get data in cache but after 7-8 days will get same error again and I have to restart redis.

Is this due to redis is not accepting for new request? Which configurations should I change?

Comment: Is there free RAM at the time of exception is happening? Maybe it is swapping?

Comment: I have already added memory policy config as allkey-lru which removes old keys when redis reaches to max memory. I have set redis cache to 7GB. I dont think its RAM issue.

Comment: Can you search for all redis*.log inside /var/log/ ?

Comment: actually logs are empty.